# Query without projection is not covered

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

See the shell example below (assumes db.test does not exist):

```
db.test.ensureIndex({info: 1, _id: 1})
db.test.insert({info: "info1"})
db.test.insert({info: "info2"})
db.test.insert({info: "info3"})
db.test.find({info: "info1"}).explain().indexOnly //is false
db.test.find({info: "info1"}, {_id: 1, info: 1}).explain().indexOnly //is true
```

The first `explain` has `indexOnly : false` whereas the second has `indexOnly : true` although the two queries are strictly equivalent.

Why isn't `db.test.find({info: "info1"})` [a covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries)?

Comment: Most likely this is a complication of the mongo query optimiser, the optimiser will not check for a covered index unless there is projection

Comment: To add I would file this on http://jira.mongodb.org cos it does seem like the optimiser should be trying to use a covered query here but clearly the optimiser isn't detecting this.

Comment: this is clearly neither a bug nor a quirk. the two queries are not in any way, shape or form "strictly equivalent".  Their results ON THIS DATASET happens to be "strictly equivalent".  But the query itself is completely different.  One says "return entire document" and the other says "return these two field values from the document".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been thinking and testing this more and it does make sense now. If you add no projection MongoDB has no way of "knowing" if the index you have actually fills the entire return; I mean how can it know the index covers the projection without looking at the documents?

It is the same as `select *` and `select d,e` in SQL. How can you know that `*` is the same as `d,e` without actually looking?

If you supply a projection then MongoDB can "know" that looking at the index will give you your full result set however, without a projection it cannot.

So after some thinking I do not think this is a bug it is just a "quirk".

Comment: That makes a lot of sense indeed. There could be a document somewhere with an additional field not captured by the index.